# To Find NFS Server IP - 16.04

Tags: networking, nfs

Let suppose, my admin has configured a NFS server( he is being HOST) in a domain network 192.168.1.0.

I am being a member of the same domain 192.168.1.0, would like to setup NFS Client on my laptop.

Consider, that I do not know the NFS server IP on me, so how would I find the NFS server(host) IP now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NFS typically use port 2049, so you could scan your network for hosts which have this port open and are listening.

This can be done for a single host e.g. using `nc` (netcat) or alternatively `telnet`:

```
nc -zvw3 192.168.1.42 2049
telnet 192.168.1.42 2049
```

If these commands succeed (`telnet` opening a connection and waiting for your input, or `nc` reporting success instead of connection refused or a timeout), you likely found the NFS.

---

Now you can either run the `nc` command in a loop to try it on all IPs in your subnet...

```
for ipaddr in 192.168.1.{1..254} ; do nc -zvw3 $ipaddr 2049 ; done
```

which might take a while if many of these addresses are offline, as it will then wait for the timeout (`-w3` sets it to 3 seconds) on each of those.

An alternative might be to install a tool like `arp-scan` (`sudo apt install arp-scan`) to find all hosts in your network using

```
sudo arp-scan --localnet
```

first, and then scan their NFS ports manually.

---

Or you could install an all-in-one port scanner like `nmap` and use that one.

The obvious solution is probably to grab the phone and simply ask your admin for the IP though...

Comment: another option is nmap which can scan a whole CIDR range e.g. `nmap -oG - -p2049 192.168.1.0/24 | grep '/open/'`

Comment: nc command worked well for me, though I forgot to report back to answer my positive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps scan for all internal IP’s and get a list of all alive hosts with their corresponding hostnames...

You can do this easily on Linux, with a GUI application such as [Angry IP scanner](http://angryip.org/download/#linux)